# Google Glass and BLE (Bluetooth 4.0, BluetoothSmart)

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Does Google Glass SDK (GDK) support BLE yet? I would like to connect and communicate with a Bluegiga BLE113 module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Yup! It was added with the upgrade to Kit Kat in XE16.

The [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=249) was closed as fixed when that release was pushed out.

Comment: Bluetooth LE software functionality is added to Google Glass as of XE18

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Google-Glass-hits-the-FCC-with-Bluetooth-4-LE-which-stock-Android-doesnt-support-yet_id39351) with the FCC filing, yes, it does. However, Android 4.0.4 does not natively support BLE, so unless the Glass Team built a BLE library for Glass, no, it doesn't. I'd suggest testing (if you have Glass). If not, I can test for you to check, if you have a way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, according to [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) it is available from API Level 18 (4.3). I can't wait to see an Android update for Google Glass.